# how to see the macros I assign

Tags: excel, vba

In excel I have a button and I am trying to assign a macro to it.
when I click assign macro I get a list with macros.
I have no other workbook open.
some of the macros  have a just the  names and other have the full address (including the name of the workbook). for the latter, the window is too small and I can widen it, so I cannot see the macro name.
I could shorten the name of the file, but the information in the file name is really important and I wouldn't like to loose it.
Any ideas? please see picture below. 
[image]

Comment: I always had this problem, then started to use a macro called "Main" and all the procedures would work from there. Every other procedure would be `Private` so it won't show there. (That is if you only need one button to execute everything you coded).

Comment: I recommend shortening the file name. Try utilizing folder names to give information so you don't have to put it in the file name. You can't resize this dialog. You can, however, put your cursor in the 'Macros in' text box and scroll to the right.

Comment: There is one small trick though, that might give you enough room to see the name, it adds at least a few more visible characters.   1) in your macro list, click the macro you want to determine the name of.  2) At the top, just to the right of the name is an up arrow with a line below it, click that.  3) that 'minimizes' the dialog, but in so doing, actually expands the space for the macro name to show slightly.  It might be enough to see your macro name (though probably not.)  When you are done, just click the same button to expand the dialog again.